# ImportError when importing pybind11 module compiled with cmake/mingw32-make

Tags: python, c++, cmake, mingw-w64, pybind11

Im currently trying to write a c++ extension to python and only have a little bit of c++ code so far ... just to test the workflow/compilation.

```
#include "conservation.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

double calculateMomentum(double mass, double velocity) {
    return mass * velocity;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(conservation, m) {
    m.doc() = "Conservation-quantity calculator";
    m.def("calculate_momentum", &calculateMomentum, "Returns Momentum of given parameters");
}
```

Then i create a makefile with the following configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.19)
project(Calculation LANGUAGES CXX)

set(pybind11_DIR $CACHE{pybind11_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../extensions)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
pybind11_add_module(conservation ./src/calculation/conservation.cpp)
```

Afterwards i can compile the extension without any problem on Windows and Linux (using mingw32-make and make respectively)

When I try importing it in Linux it works without any problems or issues and I can run the `calculate_momentum` function.

But when I try importing the extension on a Windows machine I get the following Error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing conservation: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I'm not a very experienced user of cmake or pybind11 so it is entirely possible that I am doing something completely wrong and any input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed that the import works on Python 3.7 but not on 3.8 and 3.9. Also found the following Issue on github https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/2010

Comment: It seems you are calling the function with the incorrect parameter number. Have you checked that? Also, in Windows you probably have to check if your Python version is 32 or 64 bits. Anyway, if that was the case you'd get can't find dll error. So check the parameters would be me suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try :)